# recycler view null point exception in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in fragment. When I run the app i get the following message.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

I have searched and found people with similar problems, but it hasn't helped me.   The recyclerview is null in the fragment. Here is my code:

I call the fragment from the main activity here on the onCreate:

```
 FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    trans.add(R.id.recycle_view_container, recyclerViewFragment, RECYCLER_FRAGMENT);
    trans.commit();
    trans.show(recyclerViewFragment);
```

Here is my recyclerfragment:

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
static SQLiteDatabase db;
ArrayList<MyMarker> markerArrayList;
private MyAdapter adapter;
private String TAG = "recyclerview fragment";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_view, container, false);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_in_fragment);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new MyAdapter(markerArrayList, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
```

Here is my xml for the recyclerview Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RecyclerView.RecyclerViewFragment"
android:background="#a6ffffff">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_in_fragment"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Thanks very much if you can help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried calling `setHasFixedSize(true)` after `setLayoutManager()` ?

Comment: I swapped it now. Didn't help. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use  `onViewCreated()` to access the views

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_in_fragment);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new MyAdapter(markerArrayList, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Didn;t know about that. Thanks